# Ternary Operator with a dictionary [python]

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, ternary, python-3.9

I want to optimize the code below to a **one line**

```
if i == 0:
    d = {}
else:
    d[j] = d.get(j, 0) + 1
```

i tried solving it using a ternary operator but it gave me an error

```
d = {} if i == 0 else d[j] = d.get(j, 0) + 1
```

**The error :**

> ```
> d = {} if i == 0 else d[j] = d.get(j, 0) + 1
>         ^
> SyntaxError: cannot assign to conditional expression
> ```

Can it be solved using ternary operator or is there another way to make it in a **one line**?

Comment: The conditional expression is not a shortened version of an if statement. They do different things, and a conditional expression is not always suitable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For reference, here is a one liner. I wouldn't call it an improvement though as your original `if`/`else` method is much more readable:

```
d = {} if i == 0 else {**d, j: d.get(j, 0) + 1}
```

Starting with Python 3.9 you can do the following:

```
d = {} if i == 0 else d | {j: d.get(j, 0) + 1}
```

Comment: @Daniel Look [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesmapping): "Dictionaries can be created by placing a comma-separated list of key: value pairs within braces". This is happening here via `**`. You could also do: `d = {} if i == 0 else {**d, j: d.get(j, 0) + 1}`.

Comment: @Timus Correct, that's a more concise way to write it. Updated my answer.

Comment: It is not equivalent. This one creates a new dictionary in the "else", the original mutates an existing dict. Also I don't think we should indulge users asking for dumb one-liners on here, so I downvoted, sorry!

Comment: @wim All good. You are right, it is not equivalent but functionally closest that can be implemented using the ternary operator. There is also the disclaimer stating that this is _not_ the better method.